# Imbalanced multiclass classification using keras

Tags: python, keras, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class classification problem with imbalanced dataset, I'm trying to solve this problem with multilayer perceptrons using keras. And I have assigned wights using the **class_weight** parameter. This problem has 4 classes and 22 features. 
This is the model that I have created using keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_shape = (22,), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(8, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

And this is the confusion matrix for predicted classes

```
            precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.36      0.44      0.40       117
           1       0.60      0.67      0.64       666
           2       0.69      0.60      0.64       767
           3       0.55      0.54      0.55       168

    accuracy                           0.61      1718
   macro avg       0.55      0.56      0.56      1718
weighted avg       0.62      0.61      0.61      1718
```

as you can see the accuracy doesn't improve

[image]

My question is: How can I improve the performance or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that class imbalance is a problem for you? [It typically isn’t a problem.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274) Much if the apparent problem comes from using improper, threshold-based measures of performance like accuracy, precision, and recall. I [posted](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114579/73930) about proper scoring rules on Data Science yesterday.

Comment: Hi Arwa, great to have you on Data Science Stack Exchange. In relation to your question, it would be great to see the extent of your class imbalance. It would be good for you to review your feature selection (and engineering process) as this a place where you get some performance increases, by engineering/identifying features which have a strong/significant relationship with the outcome.